# Is Stack Overflow appropriate for newbish question about a specific technology?

Tags: discussion, questions

A lot of seasoned developers temporarily become newbies when they are learning a new language, framework, etc...  Is Stack Overflow an appropriate venue for newbish questions about a specific technology?

For example:

1. Can I use the Drupal API to get a list of users?
2. Does [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) have a function to escape HTML entities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Absolutely!** Just do some basic searching to make sure that your question isn't a duplicate, and you'll be fine. One of the goals of Stack Overflow was to become a repository of any programming question someone might have, no matter how simple.

[From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) (emphasis added):

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programming questions, of course! As long as your question is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere
>
> ... it is welcome here. **No question is too trivial or too "newbie".**

> **See also:**
>
> - *[Closing ‘easy’ questions - yes or no?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/closing-easy-questions-yes-or-no)*
> - *[Should easy questions be left for beginners? That is, beginners like answering questions too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/should-easy-questions-be-left-for-beginners-ie-beginners-like-answering-question)*

Answer (score 0):

[Pseudo officially suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)