# Should we close all Yes or No Questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Are yes or no questions useful on Stack Overflow?

Not all yes/no questions are [easy to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3251/155556).

One such example of a non-closed Yes-No **constructive** question: [Should this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2828816/561731)
The OP is asking if it should work -- Yes or No,
but yet the answer turns in a completely different direction.

A second example of a **closed** constructive question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9056156/561731
The OP was curious as to why the browser showed no output, and the answer clearly explained why.
That one should **not** have been closed, because it seemed very constructive based on the answers given.

---

***Wow* this one is a yes no question, but under the flag of meta discussion**

Comment: Any meaningful examples you could share?

Comment: @MartijnPieters not that the moment, but I am sure they exist in some manner.

Comment: Since this is a Meta discussion, it's okay to make it CW from the start, right?

Comment: @Pekka Of course ^_^

Comment: Either way, I don't really see how this is constructive without some real world examples or a real world problem that needs solving. I guess the only answer that can be given is "it depends"

Comment: @Pekka I am trying to find constructive examples, it is harder than it seems....

Comment: @Pekka Found an example!

Comment: Okay, but I still don't get what the point of this question is. That example clearly got an useful answer, so there is no real issue here, is there?

Comment: @Pekka one sec, I found an example of a **Closed** constructive question.

Comment: @Pekka I added it.

Comment: But that question is closed because it is too localized. Not because it is a yes/no question.

Comment: @Pekka hmmm that seems like it is so, but I am just right now going through closed questions with the would "Should" in the title to find examples.

Comment: I think its clear that the fact that a question imposes a dichotomy is not a valid basis for closure. Perhaps "Is editing Yes/No questions so that they're not" is a more interesting question

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter not all Yes-No Questions get real yes-no answers -- is what I am saying.

Comment: Are you suggesting that yes/no questions require a yes/no answer?

Comment: Yes. Yes I am, and There should not be anything wrong with that al long as it is a legit question.

Comment: Imagine if we closed this question because it's a yes/no question.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn hehe hence my comment in the OP.

Comment: Most of those questions have an implicit "Why?" attached.

Comment: related: [Question closed because yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer)

Answer (score 5):

I say no. Let me give an example:

> **Is It Safe to use std::copy on a string?**
>
> Hi, I was wondering, can I use std::copy like this?
>
> ```
>    const char *input = "Hello World";
>    std::string copyTo;
>    std::copy(input, input + strlen(input), copyTo.begin());
> ```

That is a perfectly legitimate Yes/No question, with one correct answer (No).
While the question may be able to be reworded to a fashion that is easier to read (e.g. `How To Copy a string in C++`), that doesn't make the current question invalid.

My general philosophy is when in doubt,  edit to fix, don't vote to close.