# Let me rephrase the question about VCS hosting so that it isn't directly asking for a list but is rather a "Can I do this?" question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, undelete, list-questions

I asked the question [Which public hosting sites for darcs projects are there? (Like Gitorious for Git.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300954/which-public-hosting-sites-for-darcs-projects-are-there-like-gitorious-for-git), but it got deleted a while ago.

Let me rephrase it as:

> I want to put my darcs project onto a public hosting service (like Gitorious). Can I do this, and how/where?

Then it isn't directly asking for a list, so it doesn't have the form that is strictly banned here.

Comment: then why don't you edit it? Also, the problem with these types of questions is that there are so many link-only answers - right now all 4 answers on that are link-only.

Comment: @Doorknob It was deleted in April 2013.

Comment: okay... why does that matter? (yes, it was deleted on April 9)

Comment: @Doorknob I thought it was locked. Ok, I'll try to edit it. Thanks! No, I can't edit it.

Comment: You can't? You should be able to. What does it say when you try to edit it? (If you can't then I can edit it for you)

Comment: @Doorknob "edit" is greyed-out. And when I click it, nothing happens. Thanks for suggesting your help! But I'm not sure you should bother youself with this: as we can see, we see that such a rephrasing won't help this question survive. Anyway, all this useful information about public darcs hosting is available at http://darcs.net/Hosting (but I found that page much later than I asked the question). If I feel like copying something from the deleted question and its answers to the page at darcs.net and its duscussion page, I'll do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question closed because yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer)

Comment: Why not move this to http://meta.stackoverflow.com where this should belong?

Answer (score 11):

Your rephrasing is no different than the original question.

It's not asking for lists that is "banned"; asking questions to which there is no minimally finite set of answers are not encouraged because there is not set of answers that will satisfy everyone.

Stack Overflow is not here to answer every possible programming question. We're here to answer what can be answered *and* agreed upon by the community. We're here to give you the *best* (hopefully) answer to your programming problem, not 10 different libraries that might possibly be of use to you. If your question has many possible answers the chances are that it's not on topic on the entire Stack Exchange network.