# How should we handle "Am I correct" questions (when they're correct)?

Tags: discussion

Example question - [Running time of a loop up to i*i <= n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446149).

In this question, the user posted the correct analysis of the running time of a function in the question.

"You are correct" doesn't seem sufficient for an answer, although it could be (and is) a comment. But a question that can't have an answer can't be an acceptable question, can it?

The specific cases I'm referring to here are those where the analysis is already complete - there is not much to be added or elaborated upon (because adding this would have made for a sufficient answer).

Seems like it would've been a good candidate to be closed as "too localized" (which is no longer an available reason).

Comment: related / duplicate: [Question closed because yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer) -- I think [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773) covers things pretty well "When asking a yes/no question there are one of two possibilities..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In these cases, where the OP asks a question, provides an answer in the question body including all of the analysis and simply asks "Am I correct", since "Yes, you are correct" is not a suitable answer, I would encourage the OP to remove the answer from the question and repost it as an answer.

However, when "No, you are not correct" is the answer, then you can write your own answer and explain why.

I don't think that just because the OP answered his own question in the post and is seeking confirmation means that it should be closed, but I also don't think the format is suitable for SO, which is why I am encouraging posting the OP's confirmed correct answer as a real answer.

Comment: And if his answer was not OK, he gets downvotes. I disagree.

Comment: @MM. I was specifically referring to cases where "Yes, you are correct" is the appropriate answer.